# How to refer to data from past bars

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine-script and the documentation on tradingview isnt very clear.  I am trying to calculate a the change of volume by the change of price.  Here is my code:

```
V0 = volume
v1 = volume(1)
v2 = volume(2)
v3 = volume(3)
v4 = volume(4)
v5 = volume(5)

avgVol = (v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5)/5
volChange = v0 - avgVol
volPercentage = volChange / avgVol


p0 = close
p1 = close(1)
priceChange = p0 - p1
priceChangePercentage = priceChange /  p0

changePercentage = volPercentage * priceChangePercentage

study("My Script")
plot(changePercentage)
```

I am trying to refer to the data from past candles like ie: p = price(1), v1 = volume(5)

How is the syntax to do that? Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use brackets instead. For instance:

```
v1 = volume[1]
```

...

In addition, note that `study()` must come before all the rest of the code.

I would like to add that the documentation does help a lot. Have a look here:
[Using series in Pine-script](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#series)

Good luck!